# Dual of a norm Cone.

Tags: lp-spaces, convex-cone, dual-cone

**Problem**

> [image]
> *[`Example 2.25` Taken from [Convex Optimization](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Convex_Optimization/IUZdAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) By Stephen Boyd, Lieven Vandenberghe]*

In this example, it proves that the dual of a norm cone is the cone of corresponding dual norm. However, it only talks about $Lp$ norm with $p>1$. I think it also applies for $0<p<1$, but I don't know how to prove it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: How does Boyd define "dual norm"?